# Protect sheet after specific date on Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet containing multiple tabs. I found the script below that will protect the sheets after specific dates.  It works perfectly. HOWEVER, my spreadsheet (I am the Owner.) has other editors. When a sheet is protected by means of the script, the editors can still edit the cells. Please help me to edit the script so that only me, as Owner, can edit the data of protected sheets. Much thanks.

```
function onOpen() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheets = ss.getSheets(); //Getting all the sheets from the file.
  const lockDates = ss.getSheetByName("LockDates").getDataRange().getValues(); //Getting list of sheets and their lockdates.
  const now = new Date(); //Getting today's date.
  
  for (i=0; i < sheets.length; i++){
    var currentSheet = sheets[i];
    var sheetIndex = (lockDates.flat().indexOf(currentSheet.getName())/2); //This is to get the index where the current sheet name is located.
    if(sheetIndex >= 0){ //If the sheet is not on the list we get -1.
      var sheetLockDate = lockDates[sheetIndex][1]; //Assiging the lockDate to a variable.
      if (now >= sheetLockDate && sheetLockDate > 0){ //Evaluating if today's date is on or after the lockDate.
        currentSheet.protect();
        console.log('Sheet -' + currentSheet.getName() + '- was protected');
        break;
      } 
      else { //The sheet is unprotected if it's still not time to protect it.
      currentSheet.protect().remove();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to follow this topic "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73251805/protect-sheets-after-time" but I am unable to modify it to match what I have in mind.

Comment: onOpen runs of off a simple trigger.  Simple triggers cannot perform operations that requrire permission.  Try an installable trigger instead

Comment: Please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can further help you.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for responses. Unfortunately, I am not an IT/Coder guy. All i know is to copy/paste the script to my spreadsheet. So please help.